Intellisense in ReSharper 2024.1.2 extension for Visual Studio 2022 can sometimes stop providing suggestions upon pressing Ctrl + J (C#)
Sometimes ReSharper's IntelliSense just stops working for no reason until I manually invoke it, then it continues to operate as if nothing happened. Has anyone experienced this issue?

Have you tried the Jetbrains support forums?

What completion type is specified in your ReSharper settings in the "ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | General"?

For this random issue, please check the following suggestions to see if these help you.
1.Please run the following command to check your resharer log to see if there is any error information.
devenv /ReSharper.LogFile C:\resharper_log.txt /ReSharper.LogLevel Verbose

Note: please add "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio your version 2022\Common7\IDE" in your env variables.
2.As stuartd said, you can report this issue in JetBrains forums to get their support.
3.Here is a similar ticket that may caused by incompatibility.
Did you update Visual Studio recently?
4. Please  switch it off and   switch it back on again and  see if the issue persists.


Ok. I will try!
